# Merge request: Steam/Steam Inventory/Steam Trade

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-merge-request

[steam-inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-inventory) and [steam-trade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-trade) are both simply features of [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam).  I see no reason to have them separate.

Comment: Personally, I'd toss [tag:steam-trading-cards] in the same pot, but I could see the argument for having it separate so I'm not going to fight on that one.

Comment: +1 This sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Oops, I forgot I'm a mod. Hold on, I can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Done.

[steam-trading-cards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-trading-cards) still lives.

...For now!

Comment: +1 for the cliffhanger.